# Switch setOnCheckedChangeListener not working properly

Tags: android, android-switch, oncheckedchanged

I have a Switch named aSwitch. I have the following code in my setOnCheckedChangeListener :

```
    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (!compoundButton.isSelected()) {
                Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Selected");
                invertLock(-1);
            }
            else {
                if (Utilities.isLockEnabled(context)) {
                    Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Locked");
                    Utilities.showLockEnabled(context);
                }
                else {
                    Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Locked");
                    invertLock(1);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

The first state of the Switch is always selected=false. When I click on the switch, it gets selected=true and my Logcat shows

```
I/Yeah: Is Not Selected
```

Then when the switch is selected=true, and then turned off, my Logcat once again shows

```
I/Yeah: Is Not Selected
```

Is there any problem in my code? Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `compoundButton.isChecked` instead of `isSelected`.

Comment: or you may check b or replace it by some semantic word like hasChecked and try if(hasChecked )

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
    CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Selected");
            invertLock(-1);
        }
        else {
            if (Utilities.isLockEnabled(context)) {
                Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Locked");
                Utilities.showLockEnabled(context);
            }
            else {
                Log.i("Yeah" , "Is Not Locked");
                invertLock(1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer sir.. Both methods working fine now